# Multi-conditional if statement

Tags: c#, controls

I could have sworn I knew how to do this ... regardless, I want to check if a control matches the name of two other controls. If it matches ***either*** of the control's names, I want it to abort the "mission" if you will.

```
private void DisableMessageControls(Control myControl)
        {

// if the control is checkbox3 OR panel7 I do NOT want to execute the below code!
            if (myControl.Name != checkBox3.Name || myControl.Name != panel7.Name)
                if (checkBox3.Checked == true)
                {
                    myControl.Enabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    myControl.Enabled = false;
                }

            foreach (Control myChild in myControl.Controls)
                DisableMessageControls(myChild);

        }
```

Comment: So, what isn't working? What errors/exceptions are you getting?

Comment: don't you want to say `if (myControl.Name != checkBox3.Name && myControl.Name != panel7.Name)`

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't specify. EVEN IF the current control is checkbox3 OR panel7 it still runs the rest of the code inside the if statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got || combined with *negative* conditions. It's like saying, "If my name isn't Jon *or* it isn't Jeff." Well it can't be both, so that condition will always be true. I suspect you really want:

```
// Do you really need to check names instead of just references?
// You could probably just use
// if (myControl != checkBox3 && myControl != panel7)
if (myControl.Name != checkBox3.Name && myControl.Name != panel7.Name)
{
    // No need for your if block here
    myControl.Enabled = checkBox3.Checked;
}
```

I would also encourage you to *always* use braces, even for single-statement `if` bodies - that makes it clearer that the `foreach` isn't meant to be part of the `if` body.

Comment: I have a feeling the names are what were getting me into some trouble here.

Comment: @Evan: No, it isn't - it was the bad logic (using || with two conditions which would never *both* be false). But using the names does seem pointless if you're just identifying exact controls.

Answer (score 2):

Your if statement will always return `true` (assuming checkBox3 and panel7 have different names).

I think what you want is one of:

```
if (myControl.Name != checkBox3.Name && myControl.Name != panel7.Name)
```

or:

```
if (!(myControl.Name == checkBox3.Name || myControl.Name == panel7.Name))
```

Answer (score 0):

reading it in english can help
what you have is:
 if myControl.Name is not equal to checkbox3.name or is not equal to panel7.name
what you want is:
 if myControl.Name is not equal to checkbox3.name or equal to panel7.name

```
if (!(myControl.Name == checkBox3.Name || myControl.Name == panel7.Name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up using:

```
private void DisableMessageControls(Control myControl)
{
    if (myControl.Name == checkBox3.Name || myControl.Name == panel7.Name || myControl.Name == tpMessage.Name)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        myControl.Enabled = checkBox3.Checked;
    }

    foreach (Control myChild in myControl.Controls)
        DisableMessageControls(myChild);

}
```